# Unable to install to npm from github repository

Tags: git, github, package, npm, yeoman-generator

I have a public github repository at: https://github.com/OptiRTC/generator-optidoc

I want to publish it as an npm package. It has a package.json file with the following repository property:

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/OptiRTC/generator-optidoc.git"
  }
```

Via Git Bash, this works fine and without prompting for a user name/pwd:

`git clone https://github.com/OptiRTC/generator-optidoc.git` (try it).

Following the steps listed at https://npmjs.org/doc/developers.html#Before-Publishing-Make-Sure-Your-Package-Installs-and-Works, I am able to use link to test that my package works once installed. However, when I get to the part of testing a local install via:

```
npm install ../generator-optidoc
```

... it fails with the comment "Permission denied (public key)."

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that cloning the repository and calling `npm install <folder>` works, so it must be something with your public key.

Is everything tick-a-dee-boo with your ssh? Do you have a public key? Try `ssh-add -L` to see if your public key is readily available.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, ssh-add -L results in "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent," so maybe that is my problem. What I don't understand though, is why I would need SSH keys configured to use a repository that's public and referenced via an https URL. Do you know why it would be?